# centering child items in gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to populate a gridview with image thumbnails. I am unable to center the child items and a mismatch occurs when the image orientation is different i.e landscape vs portrait. The pic shows how it is coming out. I dont want to change the size of the thumbnails but to display the text view on the same level and the imageview to be centered accordingly.

[photo gridview with childs not centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpCCI.png)

Gridview XML:

```
<syook.syookfirst.classes.Utils.ExpandableHeightGridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview_call_photos"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit">

    </syook.syookfirst.classes.Utils.ExpandableHeightGridView>
```

ExpandableHeightGridView class:

```
public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView
{

boolean expanded = false;

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public boolean isExpanded()
{
    return expanded;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
    if (isExpanded())
    {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
{
    this.expanded = expanded;
}
}
```

Gridview child layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_nocolor_all"
    android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/photo_thumb_calldetails"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/label_photo_name"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />
```

Appreciate any help on this. I tried searching for such issues but haven't been able to resolve it with any of the solutions provided.

Comment: It looks to me like your view is centered but they are not the same size. Have you tried to put a fixed height for the ImageView like 78dp for example an see how it display ?

Comment: Setting the height to 100dp works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the height of ImageView to 100dp works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just set fix width and set gravity to center.
android:layout_width="8" and 
 android:gravity="center"